# Trying to return a string for each number of same characters that share the same index in two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following code myself (based on some instructions explained in the doc string):

```
def find_correct(answer, guess):
'''
(list, list) -> list
Given the answer code and a guess code, return
a list containing the string 'b' for each correctly positioned
colour in the guess. For example, if answer is 'YOGB' and guess is
'RTLB', ['b'] will be returned since index 3 in both is B. If answer is 'YOGB'
and guess is 'YTLB', ['b','b'] will be returned since index 0 in both is Y and
index 3 in both is B (ie. two 'b's in the list since two indexes match)
'''
for i in range(len(guess)):
    if answer[i] == guess[i]:
        return ['b']
```

However this only returns one ['b'] no matter how many indexes match (unless none match in which case nothing is returned), since I just wrote return ['b']. I don't know how to make it return more than one b. I tried a few things like:

```
 return ['b'] for i in range(len(guess)):
     if answer[i] == guess[i]
```

And doing

```
  return ['b'] * i
```

But obviously none of these work for reasons I think I understand (but I thought I'd try anyway). Is there an easy way to make the code do what I want without completely re-writing the code I already wrote or should I go back to the drawing board? Maybe perhaps there is some way i could use the a.count(b) function then multiply that result by ['b']? Just an idea I've been trying to work with. Thanks!

Comment: Very generally speaking, the answer to "how do I return more than one thing from inside a loop?" is "create a list, append to the list inside the loop, then return the list after the loop ends"

Comment: One thing worth noting; you're DocString is incorrect. In the second example [If answer is 'YOGB'
and guess is 'RYLB', ['b','b'] will be returned since index 0 in both is Y and
index 3 in both is B], the 0 index does NOT match, thus only ONE 'b' should be returned

Comment: Thank you noticing knowa42, I've corrected it now, and thanks Kevin. I asked a question to the person below about using append maybe you can help me answer it since you also mentioned append: why does .append() work in this scenario? I thought it joined two lists together or added something into a list but here it returns the 'b' by the number of times answer and guess share the same str at the same i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want this :

```
def find_correct(answer, guess):
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if answer[i] == guess[i]:
            l.append('b')
    return l
print(find_correct('YOGB','RYLB'))
```

Output:

```
['b']
```

Remember that whenever `return` is encountered, you come out of the function. So, make a list and return it at the end.

If you want a one liner,

```
def find_correct(answer, guess):
    return ['b' for i in range(len(guess)) if answer[i] == guess[i]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question - why does .append() work in this scenario? I thought it joined two lists together or added something into a list but here it returns the 'b' by the number of times answer and guess share the same str at the same i?

Comment: @Rir8 So basically everytime `answer[i]==guess[i]`, I need to append a `b` to the list, isn't it? And that's what I am doing. `append()` adds an element to a list. `list1.extend(list2)` joins two lists.

Comment: Also, why does the single liner work as a single line but it does not work when that single line is approximately changed into several lines (like what I was doing). I guess the question is why mine failed without append

Comment: @Rir8 The one liner is `list comprehension`. It builds up the list and is then returned. In your case, I am getting error as it is not valid syntax. Also it seems that you want to return `b` everytime a match is found. Thats wrong. Once `return` is encountered, execution is over. So, build up your answer before returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're close to the right answer! Like many have said, you just need to make a list and append 'b's to it until you're done. Then, return that list! See below:

```
def find_correct(answer, guess):
    return_list = []
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if answer[i] == guess[i]:
            return_list.append('b')
    return return_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is through a list comprehension.

```
def find_correct(answer, guess):
    return ['b' for a,g in zip(answer, guess) if a == g]
```

What this does is iterate through both `answer` and `guess` one element at a time and add `'b'` to the new list if the elements are the same.

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) takes a series of iterator and returns an iterator that gives a tuple with each element being the next element of the corresponding iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use `itertools` and `product`, and as others suggested use `lists`:

```
def find_correct(answer, guess):
    l = [(a,b) for a,b in itertools.product(answer, guess) if a==b]  
    return ['b']*len(l)

find_correct('YOGB','RTLB')
['b']

find_correct('YOGB','YTLB')
['b', 'b']

find_correct('RYLB','RGBY')
['b', 'b', 'b']
```